# Global Color Palette for Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uicolor, ibinspectable

In swift i'm writing an extension (like Obj-C category) that maintains in code class methods of "house colors." I'm wondering if there is a way to make this color extension accessible to Interface builder using IBInspectable or something else as opposed to attaching colors specifically to UIView subclasses as i've seen in a lot of IBInspector sample usage.

```
extension UIColor {
    // house blue
    @IBInspectable var houseBlue: UIColor { return UIColor(red:(51/255), green:(205/255), blue:(255/255), alpha:(1)) }

    // house gray
    @IBInspectable var houseGray: UIColor { return UIColor(white:0.4, alpha: 1) }

    // house white
    @IBInspectable var houseWhite: UIColor { return UIColor.whiteColor() }
}
```

Comment: This would be awesome! But it's not possible of my knowledge. You can however add a custom color palette inside the Interface Builder, but I think they're only available for usage in there.

Comment: Are you trying to only use it in storyboards but not in your actual code like `UIView.backgroundColor = x`?

Comment: Both, really. @CodyWeaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I have found to this problem is to build an asset catalog of house colors, which can be used by Interface Builder.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't programatically define colors that will then show up in Interface Builder, but you can extend `UIColor` for custom colors to use in your code:

```
extension UIColor {

   static func myCustomColor() -> UIColor {
     return UIColor(red: 23/255.0, green: 175/255.0, blue: 72/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }

}
```

And to reference the custom color:

```
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.myCustomColor()
```

This doesn't completely solve your issue, but it could potentially be better to set colors programatically than through IB. It would allow you to adjust a value one time in code to change a color throughout the app rather than having to adjust it multiple times for each UI element through Interface Builder.